# Логика внутри ViewHolder

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview

В общем я хочу просто поинтересоваться у весьма знающих людей. Работая с RecyclerView, у меня возникла необходимость использования дата байндинга фрагмента, на котором будет отображаться ресайкл, так как в качестве одного из элементов карточки этого ресайкла я использую кнопку, открывающую PopupMenu с действиями удаления и редактирования (редактирование в свою очередь открывает BottomSheet, являющийся элементом фрагмента с ресайклом). Вопрос состоит в следующем - является ли передача байндинга и вью модели фрагмента в качестве параметров ViewHolder'а плохой практикой реализации?

Comment: не просто "плохой", а "ужасной". правильно будет передавать колбэк в сам адаптер. а раз используется котлин, то лучше даже функциональный тип.

Comment: Хорошо, это не сложно, но как мне известно - адаптер должен заниматься тем, что принимает список, только и всего, т.е. ни о какой логике он знать не должен. Или я неправильно понимаю?

Comment: да, вы правы. но то, что вы передадите колбэк по нажатию на какой-то элемент - это не логика. адаптер будет знать что надо что-то исполнить, а вот "что?" - уже не знает, этим занимается тот, кто создает объект колбэка.

Comment: Я вас понял, спасибо большое :)